# Print each param name and their value

Tags: powershell

I would like to print all the params (name/value) that my script received, for diagnostic purposes. But I don't want to name one by one - that would be too boring and complicate maintenance. Is there a way to iterate over the list of params and print their values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatic variable $PSBoundParamters should give you that.

From Get-Help about_automatic_variables

```
$PSBoundParameters
   Contains a dictionary of the parameters that are passed to a script
   or function and their current values. This variable has a value only
   in a scope where parameters are declared, such as a script or function. 
   You can use it to display or change the current values of parameters 
   or to pass parameter values to another script or function.

   For example:

     function Test {
        param($a, $b)

        # Display the parameters in dictionary format.
        $PSBoundParameters

        # Call the Test1 function with $a and $b.
        test1 @PSBoundParameters
     }
```

Comment: $params = $PSBoundParameters
foreach ($keyValue in $params.GetEnumerator()) {
 Log "$($keyValue.Key) = $($keyValue.Value)"
}